# Django Form : after correctly submitting form I got this: "this field is required"

Tags: django

[image]

I've a category and I've added a form for user in each category.
So I've two fields to fill and after filling them correctly I submit but the page reload, and nothing appears in my DB... only one error on Image field: This field required. I don't really know what's wrong here.

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    catego = models.ForeignKey(Catego,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="catego_pictures")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_pictures')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='nutriscore/')
    pictureoption = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=Pictureoption.choices,default=Pictureoption.HOME,)
    publishing_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)


class CreatePictureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(CreatePictureForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method="post"
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field("image",css_class="single-input"),
            Field("pictureoption",css_class="single-input"),
            
        )
        
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit','Upload a pic',css_class="single-input textinput textInput form-control"))

    class Meta:
        model = Picture
        fields = [
            'image',
            'pictureoption',
        ]
    
def __str__(self):
    return self.catego.name
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/cooker/login')
def catego(request, slug):
    catego = Catego.objects.get(slug=slug)

    context = {
        'catego': catego
    }

    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = CreatePictureForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.catego = self.object 
            form.instance.user = self.request.user
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

    else:
        form = CreatePictureForm()

    context['form'] = form # add `form` to the context
    return render(request, 'post_catego.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer

```
@login_required(login_url='/cooker/login')
def catego(request, slug):
    catego = Catego.objects.get(slug=slug)

    context = {
        'catego': catego
    }

    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = CreatePictureForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.catego = catego
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

    else:
        form = CreatePictureForm()

    context['form'] = form # add `form` to the context
    return render(request, 'post_catego.html', context)
```